# Using many Ajax action on Extbase TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase

i already got one Ajax action on my controller, now i want to create more other Ajax Actions. I have tried to modify the setup.txt but have no luck. My setup.txt:

```
ajax = PAGE
ajax {
  typeNum = 99
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
  }
  10<lib.silver
}

ajax1 = PAGE
ajax1 {
  typeNum = 100
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
  }
  10<lib.silver
}
```

My first Ajax with typeNum = 99 work but typeNum = 100 does not work.

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly doesn't work for you? Did you try to add `type=99` and `type=100` to URLs?

Comment: I'm curious why you would think you need more than one pageType anyways? You should be able to just pass on parameters to lib.silver to call its actions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you come in conflict with other extensions which use the given pageType.
Especially the values of 100 and below are used quite often.

for example: ext:directmail uses 99 for text-rendering and 100 for html-rendering of the newsletters.

your definition might get confused with user page-definitions for the same typeNum. try some 'random' numbers.